# How to find mail server config for existing alias mail group?

Tags: server, postfix, mail-server

I am working on Ubunut mail server, I didn't configure this server, currently there is a group configured on domain "exampleabc.com" as "group@**exampleabc.com**" which has many users to send the coming mails for them on **another mail domain "example.com"** "user1@**example.com**, user2@**example.com**...etc", both domains on the same server, I want to add another users to this group, but I can't find the configuration.

Thanks to help to find all possible configuration paths to add new users for that group.

Comment: In `/etc/aliases`?

Comment: Checked, but didn't find it there.

Comment: `sudo find /etc -type f | grep "group@example.com" ` ;)

Comment: :D I tried over the whole system "find / -type f | grep "group@example.com"", not found,
But i think it shouldn't be configured that way "group@example.com"

Comment: sorry i just updated, the users domain is different than the group domain, but both exists on same server,
and still can't find the config :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the configuration on the group domain server phpadmin page "forwarding".